# Ratchet WebSocket (failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out)

Tags: javascript, php, json, ratchet

i've created a websocket server using Ratchet and a JS client. Whenever the JS client connects to the server, the connection goes idle for 4 minutes before  it gives me a handshake timeout.
I've tried to disable the firewall, change the port, use another webBrowser, even tried the online tutorial, nothing worked so far. Please Help!

here's the Server code:

```
<?php

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

class RatchetWebSocketServer implements MessageComponentInterface{


public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

}

public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    $conn->send($e->getMessage());
}

public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    $from->send("Server returned : ".$msg);
}

public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

}

}


$server = IoServer::factory(new RatchetWebSocketServer(), 8888);
$server->run();
```

here's the JS client code:

```
function startServer(){
    try{
        var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:80/CharlieTaxi/RatchetWebSocketServer.php");

        socket.onopen  = function(){

            console.log("Socket Status: "+socket.readyState);
            //send message to socket server
            socket.send("Hello from Alfred to Server");
            socket.close();
        };

        socket.onmessage = function(msg){
            console.log(msg.data);
//            socket.close();
        };

        socket.onclose = function(){
            console.log('connection is closed!');
        };
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

}
```

Here's the request header (Chrome Browser) :

```
Provisional headers are shown // this line is in bold with a yellow warning sign on the left
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8-
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Cookie:PHPSESSID=pgo5ma6o5mlh6k9mtfcad4k6d4
Host:127.0.0.1
Origin:http://127.0.0.1
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key:sVGKPRvSUghm1xdCgBQCsA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36
```

this is the console output after it gives me the timeout:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1/CharlieTaxi/RatchetWebSocketServer.php' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
```

here's the composer.json file content :

```
{
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "0.3.*"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are connecting to your websocket incorrectly.  A websocket is not just a file you connect to, it has to be its own process.  In your command line run, navigate to the directory `RatchetWebSocketServer.php` is stored in and run

`php RatchetWebSocketServer.php`

Then in javascript connect to `127.0.0.1:8888` and the WebSocket should work.

Don't forget that every time you change your WebSocket code you need to stop that `php xx` command and start it again.

Comment: Fortunately, that's what I discovered lately. Thanks for your answer :D